# Installing python module

Tags: python, module

I'm new to python and is trying to install the pyimage module.
http://code.google.com/p/pyimage/

I'm on Windows, and have downloaded and installed 2.6 and 3.1.

I downloaded pyimage, and used cmd and cd to get to its dir.

I then got this:

```
C:\Users\Jourkey\Desktop\pyimage-0.8.13\pyimage-0.8.13>python setup.py install
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I install this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is giving you that error because Python is not in your path. By default, the Python executable is not added to the path. You will have to do it manually. An in-depth tutorial endorsed by the Python website may be found
[here.](http://showmedo.com/videos/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96)

Comment: Thanks, but there's no 'scripts' dir in my python26. Am I supposed to ignore that part?

Comment: Thanks. :) Unfortunately still getting the same error. Could anything else be the problem?

Comment: You will need to close your terminal and re-open it again after adding it. Otherwise, you are supposed to add the main Python installation directory (i.e. C:\Python26) to your PATH, since that is where the executable is located in. The scripts directory exists for external packages that may be run from the command line, such as easy_install.

Comment: Ahah, it was closing and reopening that got me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To put Python on your system's environment PATH variable, so that running python at a command prompt will work, follow the instructions in [this video](http://showmedo.com/videos/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96).